# Import a Rails project to another or merging the two

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to move files from Project B to Project A.

There are answers on stackoverflow about Modules, but that also looks like a lot of work to refactor the Project B as a module.

Another way is the manually move the files from Project B to Project A, but there would be sync issues when the files from Project B are updated. Is there an easier solution?

The reason I am doing this is Project B is a checkout system that can be used for various projects.

Comment: You have to address the sharing of Rails code in four pieces:

Sharing of model definitions

Sharing of views

Sharing of controller code

Sharing of modules

Each has a different approach.

You need to describe what you want to share in more detail.

Comment: I wish to share controller and models. But right now, it seems that I will have to gemify it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like  project B really needs to be gemified into a rails engine.

Answer (score 0):

When you say files do you just mean code?

You can create a gem from Project B (and treat it as an external service, if it is set up to act as such), or you actually mount Project B onto Project A. There is a RailsCast on [Mountable Engines](http://railscasts.com/episodes/277-mountable-engines?view=asciicast), or you can check out the [official documentation on Engines](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html).